# jQuery Select2 not accepting special characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Inside a click function, I am trying to use the select2 function

```
var newVal = 'Today & Tomorrow';
$("#e8_cl").click(function() { $("#e8").select2("val", newVal); });
```

This gives me an error

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: Today & Tomorrow

Not sure, if I am doing it correctly

Answer (score 0):

You can just use string function like below

```
var newVal = 'Today & Tomorrow';
$("#e8_cl").click(function() { $("#e8").select2("val", String(newVal); });
```